# ps3 account data on ps4

Tags: ps3

hey I logged into my ps3 account on my ps4 and my data transferred over. Does this work for all ps3 and ps4 compatible games or did it just glitch. I want to try it with another game but I just decided to ask instead.

Answer (score 0):

Only specific games will transfer your data over to your ps4 Typically online games such as Call of Duty. However this wont work on games such as Terraria because there is no account system on Terraria.